# Why does naming an enum value "IN" cause a syntax error?

Tags: c++, enums, keyword

I have a class with an enum for units of length.

```
class LengthUnit
{
public:
    enum Value
    {
        IN,
        CM,
        FT
    };
    static double convert(double value, Value from, Value to){
        if (from == to) return value;
        return value * getScale(from)/getScale(to);
    }
    constexpr LengthUnit(Value value) : value(value) {}

    bool operator==(LengthUnit lUnit) const { return value == lUnit.value; }
    bool operator!=(LengthUnit lUnit) const { return value != lUnit.value; }

private:
    static double getScale(Value value){
        switch (value){
        case IN: return 2.54; // 1 in = 2.54 cm
        case FT: return 30.48; // 1 ft = 30.48 cm
        case CM: return 1;
        default:
            throw QException();
        }
    }
    Value value;
};
```

An error is detected on the 6th line.

```
error: expected identifier before ',' token
         IN,
           ^
```

If I change the name of the variable from IN to INCHES, the error goes away.

What is causing this error? As far as I can tell, IN is not a keyword of C++ or Qt, so why is the name causing an issue?

Comment: Someone has defined a macro named `IN`?

Comment: the problem has nothing to do with Qt, as they probably point out somewhere IN has been defined

Comment: If you're going to use macros like this, the advice is to *not* use 2 letter names like that, or names that have a great chance of being already defined somewhere else (like `FILE`).  Make up a name that you know won't clash.

Comment: Tip #1: Ask your compiler to generate the preprocessed output, then inspect it to see what was substituted for `IN`. Tip #2: Use all-uppercase names for and only for preprocessor macros, not for constants.

Comment: I should say `enum` names, not macros.  But you get the idea -- Those names have a great chance of being already "used", either by a macro or another `enum`.

Comment: Avoid abbreviations. It make the code harder to read as you have to learn a bunch of abbreviations. Better to use `Inches, Centimeters, Feet`. Also, prefer `enum class`. Finally, I suggest you to use SI unit as the reference value (in that case `Meters`).

Comment: Alternative: Back up your code and then play a few rounds of Divide and Conquer. Remove code until the problem goes away and then see what in the stuff you just removed clashes with `IN`.

Comment: I'm going to second the suggestion by @jamesdlin. The convention of using upper-case for macros was created so you wouldn't run into situations like this - a macro redefinition will generate a compiler error and point to the problem directly, and nothing else will collide with a macro.

Comment: It's defined in several places in the Windows SDK.

Comment: note: in the switch statement, each case needs a 'break'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified what other header files you're including, so it's not really possible to give any definitive answer.

However, there are some things that you can do to resolve your name collision:

- Since clearly something else is defining an `IN` preprocessor macro, you can do: `#define IN whatever` *after* all of your `#include`s to see if your compiler will  generate an error message describing where else it was defined.
- If that doesn't work, you could have the compiler generate preprocessed output (often via a command-line option such as `-E`).  Then you can inspect it to see what got substituted for `IN`, which might give you a clue to where it came from.
- In your source (`.cpp` or `.cc`) files, you could add `#undef IN` after all of your `#include`s to undefine the earlier instance since you presumably won't be needing the earlier definition. (Do *not* do this in a header file, however.  Doing so could invite future problems.)
- Just rename your constants.  As I mentioned in my comment, all-uppercase names should be used for (and *only* for) preprocessor macros to avoid name collisions.  The practice unfortunately got corrupted to naming *constants* in all-uppercase, but I think that having a separate namespace for preprocessor macros is much more useful.